# Customize neo4j log file to JSON

Tags: json, logging, neo4j

Is there a way to change the logging format of the neo4j.log file? Specifically to log as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

From the Neo4j Documentation: [Section 4.2 File Locations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#table-file-locations-environment-variables): **4.2.1 Where to find important files**; sub-bullet [3] Explains that to view the *neo4j.log* file one should use `journalctl --unit=neo4j` to query *systemd*.

According to the `journalctl` [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/journalctl.1.html), there is an option to format your output with many possible formats, namely: `journalctl --output=json`

So your solution might be something like:

`journalctl --output=json --unit=neo4j`
Or
`journalctl --output=json-pretty --unit=neo4j`